# Why is k9copy no longer in use?

Tags: 13.10, dvd

Trying to install this under 13.10, but see it hasn't been updated since 12.10 - is it no longer worth using? If it is, how do I install manually on 13.10?

Comment: [Binary packages](http://tomtomtom.org/k9copy-reloaded/en.html) for k9copy reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author no longer believes in linux
http://k9copy.sourceforge.net/web/index.php/en/nouveautes/12-theend

Comment: Thanks! Pity - is it worth installing an older version?

Comment: Thank you. It took awhile to find this simple answer, and it explains so much. I was a big fan of the program, and it's too bad.

Comment: The page is no longer available, but here's [an archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140321081318/http://k9copy.sourceforge.net/web/index.php/en/nouveautes/12-theend).

Answer (score -1):

At least there is one PPA to install K9Copy in recent (K)Ubuntu versions, although I haven't tried it:

https://launchpad.net/~cwbennech-gmail/+archive/ppa

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/k9copy